# tns plugin add nativescript-floatingactionbutton Installation Failed

Tags: npm, nativescript, node-modules

I wanted to use the Floating button in my App.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-floatingactionbutton
```

But the Installation failed. Below is the installation error.

[image]

I tried this also

```
sudo npm i nativescript-floatingactionbutton
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a permission error, since it is not able to write to your node_modules folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! Your answer is quite short and has more the character of a comment. 
  Please read our guide How to write a good answer and try to improve yours. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird. It's not working with npm install but it's working with yarn add. I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `sudo` doesn't work you just have to do `su` first then Enter, then type commands normally like `tns plugin add nativescript-xxxxxxx`